# Python requests Max retries exceeded with dynatrace SAAS url

Tags: python, python-requests, dynatrace

Trying to get User session data from Dynatrace SAAS using python3 script. The get Request is giving me error `Max retries exceeded with url: Failed to establish a new connection:`

I'm not sure if I'm passing the token or proxy wrong.

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

try:
    response = requests.get('https://jbu0001.live.dynatrace.com/api/v1/userSessionQueryLanguage/table?SELECT%20*%20from%20usersession&explain=true',
                           headers={'Authorization': 'Api-Token XXXXXXXX'}, proxies={'http': 'http://proxy.com:PORT'}, verify=False)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        response.text
except ConnectionError as e:
    print(e)
```

*ERR0R*

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jbu0000.live.dynatrace.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/userSessionQueryLanguage/table?SELECT%20*%20from%20usersession&explain=true (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000160212D5B38>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

*BUT* 
I'm able to get data using CURL with proxy from same machine.

```
curl -X GET "https://jbu00XXX.live.dynatrace.com/api/v1/userSessionQueryLanguage/table?query=select%20*%20from%20usersession&explain=true" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Api-Token XXXXXXXXX" --proxy http://proxy.com:PORT
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that proxy is under http not https? If so, try sending api-token as:

```
 headers={'Authorization': r'Api-Token XXXXXXXX'}
```

or

```
 headers={'Authorization': r'XXXXXXXX'}
```

prefix r assures that you are sending raw string data.